# How to allocate a buffer of fixed-length characters in dart?

Tags: dart, character, buffer, ascii

I need to allocate a buffer of ASCII characters of fixed length because I receive a (index,7-char chunk) tuples in random order from a distant device.

In C/C++ I would do:

```
char buffer[3*7+1];

memcpy(&buffer[indexOfTheChunk*7],incomingChunk,7);
```

How should I proceed in dart?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixed-size buffer by making a non-growable `List`:

```dart
var buffer = List<int>.filled(elementCount);
```

Dart also provides a [`Uint8List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) class specifically for creating fixed-size buffers of 8-bit bytes.

If you need to extract a Dart `String` from the ASCII bytes later, you can call [`ascii.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/ascii-constant.html) on the `List<int>`/`Uint8List`.